# langchain Rate limit error with introduction

Tags: openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I'm currently trying langchain, and after the first basic tutorial (this following code), i have a RateLimitError.

```py
from langchain.llms import OpenAI

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.9)
llm.predict("What would be a good company name for a company that makes colorful socks?")
```

Here's the error:
`Retrying langchain.llms.openai.completion_with_retry.<locals>._completion_with_retry in 4.0 seconds as it raised RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details..`

To your information, i don't have any kind of plan or billing on OpenAI, is it free to use langchain with OpenAI, or is it mandatory to have billing plan ?

## solved

To fix this, I just set up billing plan on https://platform.openai.com/account/billing/overview, and i works !

Comment: I don't think you have to have a billing plan, but I think you only get some many requests per month for free, as well as the rate limit is how many you can do right after another.  I think a paid plan has many more tokens you can use, and the rate limit is increased, but not unlimited if i recall.  Read the error though, it says YOUR PLAN has a QUOTA, and if its free, then ya you are out.

Comment: yeah, but it's the first time is use openAI API, so I don't understand why I'm out of the quota

Comment: You are sending it commands too quickly, try putting in some sort of delay for a few seconds perhaps?  RateLimitError is how many in a certain amount of time, not x amount and you are done.

Comment: OpenAI is not free, check the `OPEN_API_KEY` may be you got that from the tutorial and that exceeded the quota. Open ai does provide $5 free quota(credit) when u register with them.